# Redirect output from interactive logging python script to text file on Mac

Tags: python, shell, redirect, logging, interactive

I am working with a python logging script which is interactive (requires user inputs at times) and would like the output to be both in my terminal shell as well as to a text file.  The logging is very verbose, so I can't just copy from the shell as some go past the terminal history.

I was wondering if there was a way to do this.  I'm even open to executing a separate shell script which calls the python script if that enables things easier.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `tee` command (part of coreutils) does that. Example usage:

```
the_script.py | tee the_script.log
```

This will write the script output (STDOUT) to the log file and STDOUT.